# Number of digits after decimal point in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have CSV file with data:

```
Number
1.1
2.2
4.1
5.4
9.176
14.54345774
16.25664
```

If I print to display with `pandas` I get:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df)

      Number
0   1.100000
1   2.200000
2   4.100000
3   5.400000
4   9.176000
5  14.543458
6  16.256640
```

But if I cut `14.54345774` to `14.543` output is changed:

```
     Number
0   1.10000
1   2.20000
2   4.10000
3   5.40000
4   9.17600
5  14.54300
6  16.25664
```

The first case number of digits after decimal point in `pandas` is 6, second case is 5.

Why format is changed?
What `pandas` parameters should I change so these cases are equal? I want the number of digits after the decimal point to be constant and digits after the decimal point is round to max digits after the decimal point if it possibly.

**UPDATE**:

IMO, This moment arises on data initialization, so `round` don't get to desirable result if I want use 6 digits. It only can be decreased (6->5 digits), but it can't be increased (5->6).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`pd.set_option`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html) to set the decimal number display precision to e.g. 5 in this case:

```
pd.set_option("display.precision", 5)
```

or use:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)    # with original value of 14.54345774


     Number
0   1.10000
1   2.20000
2   4.10000
3   5.40000
4   9.17600
5  14.54346
6  16.25664
```

Comment: `pd.set_option("display.precision", 5)` do not always work properly. But `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format` suit for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.round(decimals=val)` to fix number of digits after decimal to val.

Also, when you changed to `14.453`, pandas didn't needed to show 6 digits then as `16.25664` has most digits after the decimal (i.e. 5) and so now it started showing 5 digits. You can fix this to some constant value so that it doesn't changes with operations.